# How do I plot the Lorenz attractor inside an ellipsoid?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

How do I plot the Lorenz attractor given by the following code, inside an ellipsoid.

I have two things with me:

1. The Lorenz system with P=6.06739, b=2.6678, r=30 and x,y,z are functions of time.

   ```
   eq1 = x'[t] == P (y[t] - x[t]);

   eq2 = y'[t] == r*x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t];

   eq3 = z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - b*z[t];

   sol = NDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, eq3, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 5, z[0] == 10}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 30}];

   p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t], sol[[3]][t]}, {t, 0, 30}]
   ```
2. The equation of an ellipsoid with `P=6.06739`, `r=30` and x,y,z are functions of time.

$$
x^2+y^2+(z-P-r)^2=2
$$
The result that I am looking for is: the trajectories of the Lorenz system must remain completely within the ellipsoid.

Comment: Just to be clear:  do you want to create a plot that shows the portions of the trajectory inside the given ellipsoid, and omit the portions of the trajectory outside the ellipsoid?  (If so, look into the `RegionFunction` option.)  Or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: Please link to the paper from where you saw the equation in your question.

Comment: The ellipsoid in (45) of the linked paper is different from the ellipsoid you've provided, and so are the evolution equations (36–38).  Is this intentional?

Comment: The equation of ellipsoid which I have provided is something that I have obtained. However, is it possible to get the Lorenz attractor inside the ellipsoid defined in (45) of the paper?

Also, the Eqs.(36)-(38) are the same as in the code. @MichaelSeifert

Comment: Equation (36) in the linked paper has `P r (y[t] - x[t])` rather than `P (y[t] - x[t])`.  Is that a typo in what you've provided?

Comment: "Pr" is a single variable. To avoid confusion, I have typed it as only P.

Comment: Next time, [edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/269687/edit) your post if you need to add something to your question. Answers are for, well, answers to (your) question.

Comment: Thanks! This is my first time on stackexchange asking questions. So basically I've no idea how it works, still learning.@J.M.'sslightlylessbusy

Answer (score 7):

Unless I've done something wrong, it does not appear that the trajectories stay inside the given ellipsoid.  The given ellipsoid can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{P}{b} x^2 + \frac{1}{b} y^2 + \left( z - \frac{P+r}{2} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{P+r}{2} \right)^2 \leq 0.
$$
So we can define this function and superimpose it in `p1`:

```
ellipsoidfn[x_, y_, z_] = P x^2/b + y^2/b + (z - (P + r)/2)^2 - ((P + r)/2)^2 ;
p2 = ContourPlot3D[ellipsoidfn[x, y, z] == 0, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, {z, 0, 40}, Mesh -> False, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.8]];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Alternately, one can tell Mathematica to render the trajectory with a different color inside & outside the ellipsoid:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t], sol[[3]][t]}, {t, 0, 30}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u}, If[ellipsoidfn[x, y, z] > 0, Red, Blue]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

---

Concerning the edited question:  we can run the same code above with the new parameters and with

```
ellipsoidfn[x_, y_, z_] = x^2 + y^2 + (z - (P + r))^2 - 2;
```

If we do this, however, the trajectory does not stay within the new ellipsoid;  in fact, as far as I can tell, it does not even enter the new ellipsoid.
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to write the evolution equations and the ellipsoid equation in a single code? 
Since using the "Show[ ]" function only merges the two separate graphs p1 and p2.

Comment: @Math_student:  I'm not aware of any way to plot a parametric curve and a surface using the same command.  However, I've added another way to visualize the portions of the curve that are inside and outside of the ellipsoid that works solely within `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: That's something very new, thanks! Also, the ellipsoid equation which you have used is the one that I posted or from the linked paper?

Comment: @Math_student:  I *think* it's the one you used, but I did some algebraic manipulations on it to make it a bit easier to write out in code.  You should probably check my work.  :-)

Comment: My problem hasn't been solved yet. I am hoping to get correct result. But I could learn the ways of writing the code for this. Thank you!

Comment: @Math_student If what Michael showed is not what you want, then it is still unclear what you would consider the "correct" result. You need to explain more clearly what you actually want.

Comment: @Math_student:  Yes, I'm also unclear on what could be considered a "correct" result.  Either this trajectory of this ODE system is wrong (which I think is unlikely) or this trajectory does not stay inside the ellipsoid you've provided.

Comment: I want the problem to be formulated in the following way. I am not sure why I am not getting any graph though. @MichaelSeifert

Clear All;
Clear[var];
P = 6.06739;
r = 30;
b1 = 2.6678;
s1 = NDSolve[{a'[t] == P (b[t] - a[t]), b'[t] == r*a[t] - b[t] - a[t]*c[t], c'[t] == a[t]*b[t] -b1*c[t], a[0] == 0, b[0] == 5, c[0] == 10}, {a, b, c}, {t, 1, 30}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]
sol = ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[{a[t]^2 + b[t]^2 + (c[t] - P - r)^2 - (Sqrt[2])^2}] /. {s1}, {t, 1, 30}]

Comment: @Math_student:  The function `{a[t]^2 + b[t]^2 + (c[t] - P - r)^2 - (Sqrt[2])^2} /. s1` will return a scalar function (i.e., it will return a single number for every value of `t`.  So `ParametricPlot3D` won't know what to do with it.

Comment: Oh. Is there a way to evaluate the function {a[t]^2 + b[t]^2 + (c[t] - P - r)^2 - (Sqrt[2])^2} /. s1, in a way that a[t], b[t] and c[t] are the solutions of the Lorenz system? @MichaelSeifert

Comment: @Math_student:  Yes, and you've got the right code to do it.  The problem is that $A^2 + B^2 + (C - P - r)^2 - 2$ is always going to be a function that maps $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^3$.  From our conversation so far, it seems to me that you have some problems in how you're thinking about the problem at the level of the underlying mathematics.  You'll need to be sure you understand the math more fully *before* we can really help you on this forum.  If you have questions along those lines, you could try posting something on [Physics.SE] or [Math.SE] instead.

Comment: I understand the map clearly now. I think what you are saying is right. Maybe I need to look more into the Math behind this, instead of simply trying how to code! @MichaelSeifert